# Android fb like button in WebView

Tags: android, html, facebook, webview

How do I display Facebook Like button in `WebView`, so when user clicks it, it will launch new window in phone's webbrowser? I couldn't get it to work, the button displays correctly but a blank page is launched when the user clicks. Can somebody show me a html snippet that works inside webview?

Here's the code I'm using to initialize WebView:

```
final WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
web.setBackgroundColor(0xff2e2e2e);
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlCodeGoesHere, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Here's the html I've tried:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://stackoverflow.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

Thanks